# Virtual bluetooth device on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Last night, being incessantly bothered by a wrong number caller speaking a foreign language, I started searching for an app to play an audio file (with "Wong Number" in lots of languages) into a phone connection, and found lots of notes stating that it is impossible due to the way the hardware works (as well as the reverse - recording the phone conversation).

"Impossible" always makes me wonder how to do something, so I started thinking: If you had a rooted phone, and could replace the kernel, could you (in theory) create a kernel driver for a virtual bluetooth headset, and play an audio file into a phone conversation by playing it through a virtual bluetooth connection?

Like I said, just a theoretical question - I have no such plans, but I am curious.

Comment: you can't use text to speech while in a phone call? maybe if you made a custom dialer?

Answer (score 1):

If someone searches for this... It is possible for an app to listen to the audio from another app, but this only grabs data from the audio file, like track title, length and quality. To get the app to stream audio to another app requires much more communication between the two applications with a constant connection. Therefore each music app would have to be specifically tailored to work in unison with the call application. Google could do this with the generic music app and call app, because they are both developed in the same way, but other companies would have to work in collaboration with Google in order to make it compatible. Long story short, there is not enough demand for this application theory for leading companies to enlist. Also, there is probably laws against it in terms of identity theft, due to the fact you could possibly manipulate a conversation using media files from another person's voice to steal their identity.